# Creating additional dbfarm in MonetDb

Tags: linux, monetdb

I have created a dbfarm in MonetDb. then I've moved the directory of the dbfarm to another location, and the dbfarm stopped working. So I'm trying to fix that by deleting the old dbfarm and/or creating a new one
The problem is that when trying to create new dbfarm by

```
monetdbd start newDbfarm/
```

I get the error:

```
monetdbd: binding to stream socket port 50000 failed: Address already in use
```

How can I solve this?

I'm working with the latest monetDb (MonetDB Oct2014 Release)

**Update**

I've managed to somehow fix this by using

```
monetdbd set port=50001 newDbfarm/
```

before the

```
monetdbd start newDbfarm/
```

and then I have to always specify the port when using monetdb:

```
monetdb -p50001 create voc1
```

Is there a way to just delete the old dbfarm? or change the default so I will always go to the new dbfarm?

Answer (score 3):

You can stop monetdbd from using the old dbfarm

```
monetdb stop oldBdbfarm
monetdb start newDbfarm
```

It might take a while for this to complete, especially if there are queries running.

Comment: The problem is that I've moved the directory of the dbfarm to another location, and now id doesn't work because the monetdb tries to access to the original directory location. So it seems I have to access the configuration files of the monet and remove this dbfarm from the list, but I don't know how.

Comment: then do a `killall monetdbd`, or `killall -9 monetdbd` instead of the `stop`

Comment: Awesome, this worked. However I had to use `monetdbd stop ...` instead of `monetdb stop ...`. In case anyone else has the same issue as I had